# создание класса, отвечающего за вызов функции или метода call_user_func_array

Tags: php, callback

У меня есть собственные кастомные описанные классы, которые что то делают. Стоит задача реализовать класс Action с методом call, который будет любой кастомный метод или функцию любого класса.

```
class Action {
    function call($func, array $argv) {
        if (is_array($func)) {
            $target = $func[0];

            global $$target; 

            $target = array($$target, $func[1]);
        } else { $target = $func; }

        return call_user_func_array($target, $argv);
    }
}
```

В принципе, вышеуказанный код рабочий, и я могу его использовать следующим образом:

```
$func = array('browser', 'navigate');
$argv = array('google.com');
$action = new Action;
$action->call($func, $argv); /*успешно обратится к $browser->navigate('google.com') */
```

Так же я могу использовать класс Action таким образом:

```
$func = 'sleep';
$argv = array('10');
$action = new Action;
$action->call($func, $argv);  // успешно вызовет ф-цию: sleep(10)
```

Но я не знаю как вызвать подобный "сложный" метод :

```
$input->get_by_number(1)->set_value('Some value');
```

Итак, какие могут быть пути реализации класса Action что бы успешно вызывать:
1) Кастомные ф-ции (ex.

```
sleep(10)
```

или

```
doNothing()
```

2) Простые кастомные методы (ex.

```
$browser->navigate('google.com')
```

или

```
$browser->wait()
```

3) Комплексные методы (ex.

```
$input->get_by_number(0)->set_value('hello')
```

или

```
$input->get_by_number(0)->set_focus()
```

Так же важно, что бы была возможность использовать функционал класса Action в цикле, ex.:

```
foreach ($actions as $action) {
    $result[] = $action->call();
}
```

Спасибо за любую помощь!

Comment: Здесь общаются на русском.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow in Russian! As the name implies, Russian is the working language of this site. Please either translate your question into Russian or [ask the same question on StackOverflow in English](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Your question may be closed soon, but it will most likely be reopened if you choose to translate it.